# Should one use FreeTDS driver instead of MS SQL Driver for compatibility between older PHP and newer SQL Servers?

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc, database-administration, freetds

I was struggling to connect my Drupal (7.43) application (hosted on a PHP 5.4 server) to a Microsoft Azure SQL database.

I got really depressed and even found myself arguing with my company's DBA for `why did you install this database on the newest version of SQL Server?`.

### Edited:

The reason why I asked that was because of Microsoft official documentation which says one *should not connect* to newer versions of *SQL Servers* if PHP server version is under 7.*.

> System Requirements for the Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-ver15#driver-versions

According to this article, if PHP server version is 5.4, the official MS driver for such php server is 3.2 version. Therefore, if the SQL Server driver is 3.2, it should not connect to SQL Server version higher than 2014.

[image: Relation between php server and ms sql driver compatibility]

### TL; DR;

I used FreeTDS to connect 5.4 PHP application to *Azure SQL Server*! Yaay

> FreeTDS is re-implementation of C libraries originally marketed by Sybase and Microsoft SQL Server. It allows many open source applications such as Perl and PHP (or your own C or C++ program) to connect to Sybase or Microsoft SQL Server.

My operational system is *CentOS 7*.

I installed basic yum packages for http server and php database connection.

```
yum install httpd httpd-tools php php-common php-cli php-odbc php-pdo unixODBC unixODBC-devel
```

So far I understand:

- PDO stands for *PHP Data Objects*.
- ODBC stands for *Open Database Connectivity* -- which is a standard application programming interface for accessing database management systems.

Alright, I then installed FreeTDS:

```
yum install epel-release
yum check-update
yum install freetds freetds-devel
```

Then I had `/etc/freetds.conf`:

```
[MYCLIENT]
  host = myclient.database.edtech.com
  port = 6669
  tds version = 8.0 # Btw, how important is this version for old PHP servers versus new SQL servers?
```

I also had `/etc/odbcinst.ini`

```
[FreeTDS]
Driver = /lib64/libtdsodbc.so.0
FileUsage = 1
```

Furthermore, I had `/etc/odbc.ini`:

```
[MSSQLServer]
Driver = FreeTDS # Yes, ODBC will use FreeTDS, I get it.
Description = MSSQL Server
Trace = Yes
Server = myclient.database.edtech.com
Port = 6669
TDS_Version = 7.1 # Shouldn't this be same as the version in /etc/freetds.conf?
Database = ApplicationDB
```

## Conclusions

- I hope this question helps others.
- FreeTDS is a different driver
  than Microsoft's.
- PHP does not know about FreeTDS not FreeTDS knows
  about PHP version.
- As far as I understood from the answers, there is
  a ODBC bridge/layer in between them.
- Better use the newest FreeTDS
  version to make sure the connection works.

Comment: What is supported and what works are 2 different things. SSMS 17 doesn't support SQL Server 2019, but that doesn't mean it won't connect to it. The problem with using tools that don't support the software means that the behaviour may not be as you expect. If you do have those scenarios, then the recommended advice will be to upgrade, as a later version will support the functionality you are after. So just because 3.2 doesn't support Azure doesn't mean it won't work with it; it could just mean that that it's unlikely to or may not work correctly.

Comment: Is there a good reason why you're still running a version of PHP which [went out of support several years go](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php)? Especially if upgrading is going to help you with this issue.

Comment: @ADyson, yes, it's a legacy application whose the client doesn't really invest on improvements and development hours.

Comment: "despite the official Microsoft docs say it should not"....actually, they don't say you can't connect to SQL Server from PHP 5.4. They you can't (or at least it's not supported to) do that by using the Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server. FreeTDS is a different driver. By replacing the driver, you've replaced the thing which Microsoft is saying you shouldn't use. AFAIK Microsoft have no involvement with FreeTDS, so what they support is entirely up to them.

Comment: @Larnu, that's such a nice point.

Comment: @AlexandreLage "the client doesn't really invest". Ok. Up to them I guess. As long as you've warned them regularly, in big red flashing writing, about the risk they're taking and made them sign something which puts all the legal liability onto them if something happens because a known vulnerability in PHP5.4, patched in later versions, is used to attack their application? (I guess it may not be your role directly to do that, but hopefully someone did.)

Comment: @ADyson, nice to finally read from somebody what I wondered for some time and might be obvious for one: FreeTDS is another driver.

Comment: @ADyson I have started a bounty to reward a proper answer. Thank you for now.

Comment: @Larnu I have started a bounty to reward a proper answer. Thank you for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said

> The reason why I asked that was because of Microsoft official documentation which says I cannot connect to newer versions of SQL Server if my PHP version is below 7.*.

and

> Is this php 5.4 connection really supposed to work with newest SQL
>   Server despite the official Microsoft docs say it should not?

...but actually, the [Microsoft documentation you're talking about](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-ver15#driver-versions) doesn't say you can't connect to SQL Server from PHP 5.4.

They said you can't (or at least you are not supported to) do that by *using the Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server* - which is the specific product that documentation is talking about.

FreeTDS is a different driver. By replacing the driver, you've replaced the thing which Microsoft is saying you shouldn't use. AFAIK Microsoft have no involvement with FreeTDS, so what they support, and what their driver works with, is entirely up to them.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking into FreeTDS docs for some sort of compatibility description table just like the one I attached from Microsoft docs. Have you seen anything like that relating FreeTDS versions vs. PHP versions vs. MS SQL Server versions?

Comment: https://www.freetds.org/faq.html#Does.FreeTDS.support.my.server and https://www.freetds.org/userguide/choosingtdsprotocol.htm is about the closest I can find. Unfortunately it doesn't cover the very latest SQL Server versions, but since you've got it working we can assume there is at least some compatibility. I doubt you'll get a FreeTDS vs PHP compatibility, because in your case you're using ODBC as a compatibility layer in between, so in fact PHP doesn't know anything about your FreeTDS install (it only knows about ODBC), and vice-versa.

Comment: `you're using ODBC as a compatibility layer in between, so in fact PHP doesn't know anything about your FreeTDS install (it only knows about ODBC), and vice-versa` +1